# closing and opening jquery popUps add multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Using a Jquery popUp iv added a help icon beside the 'X' button on the title bar. Problem being when I close the popUp and open it again there are 2 help icons, close and open, there are 3...and so on....

I can set display to none, which removes it, but the next time the popUp is opened there are 2 hand icons...tried:

```
    <script>
    $('#helpIconBtn').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
    $('.helpIconBtn').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
    $('#iconhelp').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
    $('#iconhelp').removeClass(".helpIconBtn");
    // $('#iconhelp').css('display', 'none');
    //$(".iconhelp").removeClass
     //  $(".iconhelp").classList.remove(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
     $("iconhelp").removeClass("helpIconBtn");
     $("iconhelp").removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
    </script>
```

**Code:**

```
var floater_style_feature_panel_popup = $("#floater_Style_Features_Panel_popup");


                floater_style_feature_panel_popup.dialog({
                    resizable: false
                },
                    { width: "auto" },
                    { height: "auto" },
                     { position: { my: "top+45", at: "bottom", of: $("header")} },
                    { show: { effect: "slideDown"} },
                    {dialogClass: "helpIconBtn"},
                    { hide: true },
                    { open: function (event, ui) {
                        floater_style_feature_panel_popup[0].parentNode.classList.add("opaqueDialog");

                        ResizeStylerDialog();
                    }
                    },
                    { beforeClose: function (event, ui) {

                        if (closeFeatureStyler == false) {
                            var funcParamCall = { "funcParam": [{ "funcName": "OnFeatureStylePreClose()"}] };

                            $$("FeatureStyler")[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(funcParamCall), "*");
                            alert("false");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("true");
                            //$('#iconhelp').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                            //$('#helpIconBtn').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                            //$('.helpIconBtn').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                           // $('#iconhelp').removeClass(".helpIconBtn");
                            // $('#iconhelp').css('display', 'none');
                            // $('#iconhelp').css('display', 'none');
                            // $(".iconhelp").classList.remove(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                            //$("iconhelp").removeClass("helpIconBtn");
                            //$("iconhelp").removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    { closeOnEscape: true
                    }).parent().appendTo("form:first");

                $(".helpIconBtn").children(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<span id='iconhelp' class='ui-icon ui-icon-help'></span>");

                $("#iconhelp").click(function () {
                   alert('help');

                });


#iconhelp{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

Comment: I see that you are using `#helpIconBtn` and `.helpIconBtn` which jQuery doesnt consider the same

Comment: Please share your html, and put your code in a jsfiddle, I believe you are linking the action over and over again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i see that you add one span with the id **iconhelp** in each call, if is needed add this in the call, then remove this when the popup is closed, to this, use the event beforeClose and put $('#iconhelp').remove() this delete the entire element that you are creating in each call.

```
                 { beforeClose: function (event, ui) {

                    if (closeFeatureStyler == false) {
                        var funcParamCall = { "funcParam": [{ "funcName": "OnFeatureStylePreClose()"}] };

                        $$("FeatureStyler")[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(funcParamCall), "*");
                        alert("false");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("true");
                        //$('#iconhelp').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                        //$('#helpIconBtn').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                        //$('.helpIconBtn').removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                       // $('#iconhelp').removeClass(".helpIconBtn");
                        // $('#iconhelp').css('display', 'none');
                        // $('#iconhelp').css('display', 'none');
                        // $(".iconhelp").classList.remove(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                        //$("iconhelp").removeClass("helpIconBtn");
                        //$("iconhelp").removeClass(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
                        $("#iconhelp").remove();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are appending the icon each time user opens popup and just removing the class of it during popup close.
Just check if you have more then one span with "iconhelp" id.

If so, you can fix it in two different ways:

1. Remove the span on popup close:

   $('#iconhelp').remove();
2. Instead of appending the span each time, let it be permanent and just add and remove class from it.

If you will go with first approach, do not forget to change following:

```
$("#iconhelp").click(function () {
    alert('help');
});
```

to:

```
$(document).on("click", "#iconhelp", function () {
    alert('help');
});
```